# increase font size in website on smartphones and iPhones

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a site that should look almost the same on every device. i.e. laptop, PC, ipads, iphones and other smartphones.

I am using fittext.js which is pure javascript in order to reduce/increase the font size on the website according to the user's screen resolution.

however, the fonts are very small on devices such as iphones!

how can i increase the font size a bit more on iphones and other smart phones?

this is the javascript code i am using:

fittext.js

```
(function(){
  var css = function (el, prop) {
    return window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue(prop) : el.currentStyle[prop];
  };

  var addEvent = function (el, type, fn) {
    if (el.addEventListener)
      el.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        else
            el.attachEvent('on'+type, fn);
  };

  window.fitText = function (el, kompressor) {

    var settings = {
      'minFontSize' : -1/0,
      'maxFontSize' : 1/0
    };

    var fit = function (el) {
      var compressor = kompressor || 1;

      var resizer = function () {
        el.style.fontSize = Math.max(Math.min(el.clientWidth / (compressor*10), parseFloat(settings.maxFontSize)), parseFloat(settings.minFontSize)) + 'px';
      };

      // Call once to set.
      resizer();

      // Bind events
      // If you have any js library which support Events, replace this part
      // and remove addEvent function (or use original jQuery version)
      addEvent(window, 'resize', resizer);
    };

    if (el.length)
      for(var i=0; i<el.length; i++)
        fit(el[i]);
    else
      fit(el);

    // return set of elements
    return el;
  };
})();
```

and this is in my HTML page:

```
<script src="fittext.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  fitText(document.getElementById('fittext'), 2.9)
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fittext's suggested use says that it shouldn't be used for paragraphs of information. For mobile sites ensure you have a mobile viewport set, and then the easiest way to change font size for smaller devices is to use media queries.

Comment: +1 to this -- generally speaking, you should pursue a CSS/media query based approach. That's the right tool for the job here.